# How to do a dynamic Range with Pentaho CDE Dial Component

Tags: pentaho-cde

I am trying to make the Pentaho CDE Dial Component show a dynamic range.

Here's an example. Let's say am looking at how Alex performs in respect to the total marks assignable e.g `50 out of 100`.
I do a query that outputs the two numbers in two separate columns `50 | 100`

Now I want the dial component to show a range of `0 to 100` and have the pointer to be at `50`.

But if tomorrow Alex gets `20 out of 70`, I want the Dial component to show a range of `0 to 70` and the pointer to be at 20.

Currently, my dial component picks the first number and does a range from 0 to that number. e.g if Alex scores `20 out of 70`, the dial shows a range of `0 to 20` and the pointer is at `20`.

I am picking the numbers from the query to a query component which in turn pushes to the dial component.

My intervals array looks like `[0,33,66,100]`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I solved the range issue. I had done the Intervals array in one line and each value needed to be in its own line. Now I can have a range of from 0-100 or anything else but it always has to be hardcoded in the intervals array section.

Comment: My concern now is how can I make the interval  dynamic?